# Webdriverio - How to detect a browser window being closed

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm doing automated testing with webdriverio and mocha. If a browser window is closed while my automated tests are executing I want to end the process rather than continuing to execute my tests. Is there a way to detect a browser closing? I see the information in the selenium logs but I don't know how to detect this in my actual node script. Here's the error in the selenium server log:

12:33:17.122 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check if session still exist by using `client.sessions()` . you may use this

```
describe('check if session still exist', function() {

    it('should check if session still exist', function() {
    return browser.sessions().then(function(sessionid){
    var id1 = sessionid
    console.log(id1);
      });
   });
});
```

If there is no session the above will return

```
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 1944289324,
  value: [],
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
```

otherwise it will return something like this

```
 state: 'success',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 381733075,
  value:

   [ { capabilities: [Object],
       id: '8ec2e2e8-6833-4105-8b84-1a6ce74a29ff',
       hCode: 1337873045,
       class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetAllSessions$SessionInfo' } ],
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
```

then at right place in your code based on above `value` json object, you can chose to end the process.